# HTACCESS Rewrite: Ignore another rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using rewrite rules for two purposes. First, I am able to rewrite the URL's to my .css and .js files so they can be processed through a minimize script. This has been working fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^assets/css/min/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)\.css$ assets/css/min.php?style=$1&theme=$2&ver=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^assets/js/min/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)\.js$ assets/js/min.php?scripts=$1&ver=$2 [L,QSA]
```

However, now I added a rule to redirect all traffic for nonexistent pages to my `index.php` file (for MVC routing):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteBase /
```

The problem is, now that I have both of these rules in my HTACCESS file, I am no longer able to access my .css or .js files like:

```
http://domain.tld/assets/css/min/all/default/0.2.3.css
```

How can I get the rerouting to index.php to ignore the previous rule with my css and js rewriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead in last rule to skip `assets/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^assets/css/min/([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)\.css$ assets/css/min.php?style=$1&theme=$2&ver=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^assets/js/min/([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)\.js$ assets/js/min.php?scripts=$1&ver=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!assets/)(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Also note that you can replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with shorter `\w`

Comment: How would I modify `^(?!assets/)` to add an additional directory to ignore?

Comment: You can use it like this: `RewriteRule ^(?!(assets|dir2|dir3)/)(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]`